# Recursive linq and this?

Tags: c#, linq, .net-4.0

I want to find all Persons who are left handed *using recursive linq* via extension method.

I've seen this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4814278/859154) but there is a problem (imho)  with the `this`  : *(when applied as extension method because of the static context)*

> keyword this is not valid in static method

So here is what i've tried :

I have a `Person` class :

```
public class Person
{
        public  List<Person> Children = new List<Person>();
        public bool IsLeftHanded;
}
```

And here is the code  for the externsion method :

```
public static class Extensions
{   
        public static IEnumerable<Person> DescendantsAndSelf(this IEnumerable<Person> list)
        {
         yield return this;
        foreach (var item in list.SelectMany(x => x.Children.DescendantsAndSelf()))
        {
            yield return item;
        }
    }
}
```

But there is a problem with `yield return this;`

**Question :**

How can I `fix` my code in order to support the "*me and my childs*" trick ? ( goal : find all persons who are left handed)

nb

*please notice that I want to use linq and recursion in order to get experienced with linq using recursion.*

Comment: The `this` will not work inside a static class. You should pass a Person class.

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen Yes as you can see I've written that it wont work because of the static context. well  ,  I think wudzik's solution is much appropriate. thanks

Comment: You pass an `IEnumerable<Person>`, you should pass the "root" Person. (like wudzik did +1)

Comment: @RoyiNamir is any answer helpful for you? Do you need better answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a more generic version that would work on any collection.

```
public static IEnumerable<T> SelectDescendents<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, IEnumerable<T>> selector)
{
        foreach(var item in source)
        {
            yield return item;
            foreach(T item2 in SelectDescendents(selector(item), selector))
                yield return item2;
        }
}
```

Usage

```
Persons.SelectDescendents(p => p.Children);
```

Comment: How would this return the person itself ? Look at my structure please

Comment: @RoyiNamir In you case since you don't have a collection of persons it would be: `new[]{ Person }.SelectDescendents(p => p. Children)`

Answer (score 3):

I'd rather see it working like this:

```
public static IEnumerable<Person> DescendantsAndSelf(this Person person)
{
    yield return person;
    foreach (var item in person.Children.SelectMany(x => x.DescendantsAndSelf()))
    {
        yield return item;
    }
}
```

and run it against person not children, like this:

```
var person = new Person();
... do stuff
var desc = person.DescendantsAndSelf();
```

Correct me if I see it wrong.

Comment: Dumb question, but is the point of using "yield return" (as opposed to building up a list and returning it) just to get the benefits of deferred execution, or is there another reason?

Comment: @vargonian deferred execution is the reason, read this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14057788/why-use-the-yield-keyword-when-i-could-just-use-an-ordinary-ienumerable