# Recursive Linq - Parent indication for child property?

Tags: c#, linq, recursion

I have a table (let's say DataTable for this example) which has hierarchy records ( id,ParentId,IsEmergency) :

[image]

`ParentId=0` means root.

So we have this :

```
0
|
+--- 4706606
|
+--- 4706605
|
+--- 4666762
        |
        +--- 4668461
               |
               +--- 4706607
```

I'm after displaying only the those records who has `parentId=0`

But I want to add another logical column which states "this parent has `IsEmergency=true` in one of it's childs/sub childs

So I'm after

```
id         parentId        hasEmergencyInOneOfItsChild
-------------------------------------------------------
4706606    0                false
4706605    0                false
4666762    0                true
```

**Question:**

How can I achieve it via recursive linq ?

For   convenience I created this Datatable :

```
   DataTable dt = new DataTable("myTable");
   dt.Columns.Add("id", typeof (int));
   dt.Columns.Add("parentId", typeof (int));
   dt.Columns.Add("isEmergency", typeof (bool));

   DataRow row = dt.NewRow();
   row["id"] =4706606;
   row["parentId"] = 0;
   row["isEmergency"] =false;
   dt.Rows.Add(row);

       row = dt.NewRow();
   row["id"] =4706605;
   row["parentId"] = 0;
   row["isEmergency"] = false;
   dt.Rows.Add(row);

       row = dt.NewRow();
   row["id"] =4666762;
   row["parentId"] = 0;
   row["isEmergency"] =false;
   dt.Rows.Add(row);

       row = dt.NewRow();
   row["id"] =4668461;
   row["parentId"] = 4666762;
   row["isEmergency"] = false;
   dt.Rows.Add(row);

        row = dt.NewRow();
   row["id"] =4706607;
   row["parentId"] = 4668461;
   row["isEmergency"] = true;
   dt.Rows.Add(row);
```

<strike>I've tried something but it is pretty nasty and not efficient</strike>

Comment: You're looking for a Linq query that will retrieve the data from where? What is the actual data source?

Comment: @haim770 No. I'm talking about Linq In Memory for an already existing data source (in memory- datatable). there is no SQL involved here.

Comment: @haim770 it's like a forum. each question has a parent question.

Comment: Did you look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4814242/linq-recursion-function

Comment: @haim770, run his code in LINQPad and you will have the datasource

Comment: "I've tried something but it is pretty nasty and not efficient" -- what did you try? Did it work? In what _specific_ way is it different from what you want? Please provide [a good, _minimal_, _complete_ code example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) showing what you've got so far.

Comment: @PeterDuniho No it didnt work. I went to my other question regarding [recursive linq](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21086502/recursive-linq-and-this) but couldn't adopt it to work

Comment: This isn't a LINQ problem. LINQ isn't the right instrument here. Standard coding is. And a Dictionary<> probably. As you have written it, you don't really have a tree-like structure. You only have a bunch of records with an id.

Comment: @xanatos I didn't say that Linq is a problem here. It's  jsut that I wanted to do it via linq - hence the tag

Comment: @RoyiNamir And I'm telling you that LINQ isn't the right instrument.

Comment: @closers - did I really asked : "why isn't the code working ?"

Comment: @xanatos Okay. I'll wait to see if there's answers  , if not , i'll delete and do it manually. :-)

Comment: @RoyiNamir - it's not that you've asked "why isn't the code working?", it's because you've stated: "I've tried something but it is pretty nasty and not efficient", yet have not shown what you've tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your data:

```
var lookup = dt.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().Select(x => new
{
    id = (int)x["id"],
    parentId = (int)x["parentId"],
    isEmergency = (bool)x["isEmergency"],
}).ToLookup(x => x.parentId);
```

I build a lookup "sorted" by `parentid` (let's say it's a like a dictionary but with multiple values for each key)

```
// Taken from http://stackoverflow.com/a/21086662/613130
public static IEnumerable<T> SelectSelfDescendents<T>(IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, IEnumerable<T>> selector)
{
    foreach (var item in source)
    {
        yield return item;

        foreach (T item2 in SelectSelfDescendents(selector(item), selector))
            yield return item2;
    }
}
```

A recursive function to return recursively the input collection plus the descendents

```
var roots = lookup[0].Select(x => new
{
    x.id,
    // x.parentId // useless, it's 0
    isEmergency = SelectSelfDescendents(new[] { x }, y => lookup[y.id]).Any(y => y.isEmergency),
    childs = SelectSelfDescendents(new[] { x }, y => lookup[y.id]).ToArray()
}).ToArray();
```

A little Linq to handle everything :-)

```
lookup[0]
```

We start with the "root" elements (the elements that have parentId == 0)

This one

```
.SelectSelfDescendents(new[] { x }, y => lookup[y.id])
```

given an ienumerable returns the ienumerable plus all its recursive childrens.

```
new[] { x }
```

Transforms the "current" root element in a collection of a single element.

```
y => lookup[y.id]
```

This is a descendent selector: given an element it finds in the lookup all the childs that have `y.id` as a parent (because the lookup is by parentId)

So in the end the `SelectSelfDescendents` will return `new[] { x }` concatenated with all its "descendents"

```
.Any(y => y.isEmergency)
```

if any `isEmergency` is `true` returns `true`

Now, as you noticed, I'm recalculating `SelectSelfDescendants` twice (once for `isEmergency` and once for `childs`)... In truth `childs` was a property I had added to "debug" the recursive enumeration, so it can be removed if it is not necessary. If you want to keep it, you can use the `let` keyword (or "expand" the `let` keyword as you've shown you did in chat... it is the same thing). Note that I "cache" the `SelectSelfDescendents` with a `.ToArray()` (as you did). Without it, it would still be evaluated twice, because it returns an `IEnumerable<>`

```
var roots = (from x in lookup[0]
             let childs = SelectSelfDescendents(new[] { x }, y => lookup[y.id]).ToArray()
             select new
             {
                 x.id,
                 // x.parentId // useless, it's 0
                 isEmergency = childs.Any(y => y.isEmergency),
                 childs 
             }).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 3):

One approach is to define a data structure that holds the relevant properties and a recursive property to determine whether it is in an `isEmergency` hierarchy:

```
internal class Node
{
    internal string Id { get; set; }
    internal IEnumerable<Node> Children { get; set; } 
    internal bool IsEmergency { get; set; }

    internal bool IsEmergencyHierarchy
    {
        get { return IsEmergency || 
                     (Children != null && Children.Any(n => n.IsEmergencyHierarchy)); }
    }
}
```

Then you can construct the tree like this:

```
// convert rows to nodes
var nodes = dt.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().Select(r => new Node
{
    Id = r["id"].ToString(),
    ParentId = r["parentId"].ToString(),
    IsEmergency = (r["isEmergency"] as bool? == true)
}).ToList();

// group and index by parent id
var grouped = nodes.GroupBy(n => n.ParentId).ToDictionary(g => g.Key);

// match up child nodes
foreach (var n in nodes)
{
    n.Children = grouped.ContainsKey(n.Id) 
        ? (IEnumerable<Node>)grouped[n.Id] 
        : new Node[0];
}

// select top nodes
var top = grouped.ContainsKey("0") 
    ? (IEnumerable<Node>)grouped["0"] 
    : new Node[0];
```

You can check the result like this:

```
foreach (var t in top)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0} - {1}", t.Id, t.IsEmergencyHierarchy);
}
```

Output:

```
4706606 - False
4706605 - False
4666762 - True
```