# Why do I need Iterators in real life? Without built in C# collection types

Tags: c#, loops, iterator

I have 2 realizations of a method that calculates Fibonacci numbers. Why would I need an iterator realization in real life nor the Fibonacci example? Cause I can't see the difference. Yes, I know about Interfaces but I need a real example where iterators are useful, not just in built-in collection types. Why do I need the `Fibo` iterator method if I can do like in the `Fibonacci` method?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

class Fibonacci_C
{
    static void Main()
    {
        foreach (int fib in Fibo(5))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(fib);
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(Fibonacci(i));
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static public IEnumerable<int> Fibo(int length)
    {
        int prevFib = 0, curFib = 1, newFib = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        {
            yield return prevFib;
            newFib = prevFib + curFib;
            prevFib = curFib;
            curFib = newFib;
        }
    }

    public static int Fibonacci(int length)
    {
        int a = 0;
        int b = 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        {
            int temp = a;
            a = b;
            b = temp + b;
        }

        return a;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your question is confusing.

Comment: OK. What confuse?

Comment: Perhaps this would answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17125/what-are-real-life-applications-of-yield

Comment: As far as I can tell, you're asking why you have two implementations of methods that return the Fibonacci sequence. Is that correct? Only you can answer "why".

Comment: I know why I need yield. But I think fibo example is bad.

Comment: Why I need Fibo function where I can do like in Fibonacci?

Comment: `fibo` is an example of a method that returns a *sequence*. The sequence is accessed through an iterator (an `IEnumerable`). On the other hand, `fibonacci` is a method that returns a single number. Note that running fibonacci N times uses N^2 loops since one loop is inside the method while the other is outside. Whereas fibo is just N.

Comment: DodgyCodeExceptionYes, I understood but not fully. Thanks

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because _"[your question is just a rant in disguise](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)"_

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your example, the iterator saves you from calculating already calculated fibonacci numbers over and over again. Your second method

```
public static int Fibonacci(int length)
{
    int a = 0;
    int b = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        int temp = a;
        a = b;
        b = temp + b;
    }
    return a;
}
```

when called in the `for` loop, has to calculate all fibonacci numbers up to Fib(`length`) on each call, even though it has already calculated them in previous calls. Your iterator method spares you that since it only calculates each fibonacci number once, and returns it using `yield return`.

Iterators are not the sole way of avoiding unnecessary recalculation, though.

Comment: But I do not call it in foreach loop. I call it in for loop

Comment: i meant for loop sorry

Comment: Yes, I felt something and I need check and fully understood it.